# Including double quotes while writing CSV using apache commons in java

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I am using apache commons CSV to write csv files. I want to stick to this library. While I am writing a csv file, in the first column of generated file, it contains double quotes as quote character and other columns are generated as expected.

I really want to get rid of double quotes here. Please find below code for the same.

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT;
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Temp.csv");
CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(fw, format);

String[] temp = new String[4];

for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    if(i==1)
        temp[0] = "#";
    else
        temp[0] = "";
    temp[1] = "hello" + (i+1);
    temp[2] = "";
    temp[3] = "test";

    Object[] temp1 = temp[]
    printer.printRecord(temp1);
}

fw.close();
printer.close();
```

### Temp.csv

"",hello1,,test
"#",hello2,,test
"",hello3,,test
"",hello4,,test

I don't want a quote character at the beginning of every row. I just want an empty string without quotes, same as in column 3. Can anyone help?

Comment: I know this is 5 years old, but it is outputting an empty string in the first field. That is why there are two quotes. It's interesting as when I started working with CSV files all text fields were surrounded by quotes. Maybe I was jaded because I was mostly working in the Microsoft realm at the time. Now I've come back and seems like things generate CSV's a lot more looser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue. You can vote for it in the apache commons csv issue tracker:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CSV-63

Answer (score 13):

Mentioned in lars issue tracking, try to set the CSVFormat to the following,

`final CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withEscape('\\').withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.NONE);`

Comment: tried on 1.5 version, do you know which version this works?